# Mary's dress is identical to Jane's. Is it correct to say "They are wearing the same dress" or "They are wearing the same dresses"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

There is just one school when we say "**They go to the same school**"

Say, Mary's dress is identical to Jane's. I am sure we can say "**Mary's dress is the same as Jane's**"

Is it correct to say "**They are wearing the same dress**" or "**They are wearing the same dresses**"?

Comment: I would say "they were wearing the same dress" or "she was wearing the same dress as me". But I can't tell you why just how I (Brit) talk

Comment: American here, and I would also use the singular "dress" but I can't say why

Comment: I think either option suggested by OP is at least okay. But to be completely unambiguous (in case that is important in the context) you could say, “They are wearing identical dresses.”

Answer (score 1):

I think the underlying assumption here is that they both can't be wearing the exact same dress at the same time. So if you're referencing **the dress**, you're referring to the category (kind, color, pattern, etc.) of dress, and it's singular:

> They are wearing the same dress.

As someone pointed out in the comments, if you refer to more than one dress, it's plural:

> They are wearing identical dresses.

Also, if you make the dress the subject, it needs to be plural:

> Their dresses are the same.